# add swipe cell button with text (below it)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

How to create button with text (below it) in Cell in UITableview.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the default `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

You need to build this functionality on your own by simply taking the contents of the cell on a *scrollView* with relevant buttons under the *scrollview*.

Alternatively, you can assign swipe gestures to the cell's content with buttons under the content.